# Endless 'The name '' does not exist in the current context' Errors in VS 2013 after migration

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013, intellisense

I have a problem after migrating a WPF solution from VS2012 to 2013, after almost every little change, i get many 'The name '' does not exist in the current context' - as if every WPF control in the current Window (or usercontrol) is unknown suddenly.

Debugging helps, but it is very frustrating to hit (and wait) so often for the project to rebuild and to remove all errors. After i change something, i have the same problem again, i cannot use intellisense until i build again.

I just installed VS 2013 last days and already update it with the Update 1.
Clean solution did not help.

(Edit) Added some screenshots for clarification.
I only have one usercontrol open.
[image: Before changin /typing anything]

After that, i just type in string and a space and all controls will get again unknown
[image: After typing something]

Comment: Have you tried closing all files (typically in tabs) opened in VS ?

Comment: I have only one usercontrol open. And it does happen also for others.
And also for Windows (not only UC).

Comment: I haven't encountered this one my self, but which updates have you installed?